# Mapping attributes to values in vector

Tags: r, attributes

I'm working with a dataframe where each column has different attributes. Is it possible to map specified attributes to the vector? For context, you might expect to see this situation where you have raw data and labeled data in the form of a vector and a label attribute.

Here is an example with the desired outcome:

```
foo = c(2,1,3,3,2,1)
attr(foo, "mylevels") = c(1,2,3)
attr(foo, "mylabels") = c("Red", "Blue", "Green")

## foo
## [1] 1 2 3 3 2 1
## attr(,"mylevels")
## [1] 1 2 3
## attr(,"mylabels")
## [1] "Red"   "Blue"  "Green"

## attributes(foo)
## $mylevels
## [1] 1 2 3

## $mylabels
## [1] "Red"   "Blue"  "Green"
```

The goal is something like:

```
foo[attr(foo, "mylabels")] #(which doesn't work)
"Blue" "Red" "Green" "Green" "Blue" "Red"
```

Comment: May be `attr(foo, "mylabels") <- as.character(factor(foo, labels=c("Red", "Blue", "Green")))`

Comment: @akrun Good suggestion, but that just redefines the "mylabels" attribute. I might be misunderstanding how the attributes work, but it looks like they're supposed to be unique levels.

Comment: If you are creating an `attribute`, I am not sure how it will be created without the `attr` route.

Comment: @akrun I'm not trying to create a new attribute, I'm trying to display the original vector (foo) in terms of the attributes. Does that make sense? Let me know if my question isn't clear and I'll work on it.

Comment: If you don't need an attribute, then `as.character(factor(foo, labels=c("Red", "Blue", "Green")))` should get the expected output

Comment: Unfortunately the data I'm working with already has attributes, and because the attribute labels might change I want to avoid hardcoding them in. I'm surprised this isn't a more common issue/usage!

Comment: This also should give `attr(foo, "mylabels")[foo]`

Comment: akrun, if you post your comment as an answer, i'll upvote it as it seems to fully answer this original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either convert the 'foo' to `factor` and specify the `levels`

```
as.character(factor(foo, labels=c("Red", "Blue", "Green")))
```

Or use the 'foo' as numeric index for the `attr`

```
attr(foo, "mylabels")[foo]
```